# How configure the inno settup file to use the right appSettings.json

Tags: .net, installation

I am building an installer for four different environments. dev, stage, test and prod. I need to define which file to be used each time. I am trying to use an if statement to pick the right appsetting, eg appSetting.dev.json etc.... I need to implement this inside the the "*.iss" file itself, not as part of a .net core app. Then I am using the a build and deploy pipeline to run inno settup installer, arichieve the files and publish them.But I just need to define those inside the inno file.

This will be part of a standalone app zip file.

I havent tried anything yet. I am new to .net stuff.